# How to perform espresso recording on standalone android app (.apk file) in android studio?

Tags: android, automation, recording, android-espresso

I have one app (.apk file). for what i need to do testing using espresso recorder in android studio. i don't have source code or other files except .apk which launches application in real phone. is it possible? how to do it?

how to launch this app in android studio emulator? and perform espresso recording?